# will an additional, rarely changing tag have a relevant "cost"?

Tags: influxdb

In a InfluxDB (Cloud) I store measurements of a many weather sensors.

So, each InfluxDB data point looks like this:

```
weather,deviceId=1234 temperature=21.3,humidity=66 1559260800000000000
```

To the existing single `deviceId` tag I'd like to add a second tag `position`, resulting in points such as...

```
weather,deviceId=1234,position=243 temperature=21.3,humidity=66 1559260800000000000
```

For a given `deviceId` the `position` would change **very** rarely, but it can happen.

When querying a sensor data, the `deviceId` and `position` would be filtered always together.

Will this additional tag have an relevant increase on the billed storage (GB-hr) or negatively affect performance or is InfluxDB able to optimize/compress this additional tag?

*Some more context: Some sensors might be reused and placed to a different location. It would not make much sense to analyze data of a single sensor at different positions, hence filter data always like "sensor 1234 at position 243". As this is adding a fifth value to a otherwise relatively small data point, I'm worried that this might "cost" too much.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no for both storage size and write/read performance in your case. That means, you should be fine by adding an additional tag.

> tag values are stored only once and always as strings. See more details here.

Since values of **position** are limited and far less than that of **deviceId**, the storage will be just okay. See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/hardware_sizing/#bytes-and-compression).

Regarding the write/read performance, it all comes down to **series cardinality**, which is simply

> The number of unique measurement, tag set, and field key combinations in an InfluxDB bucket.

Again, since values of **position** are limited and change very rarely, it won't add much cardinality to the database. Therefore, the write/read performance won't be impacted that much.

You could check the series cardinality of the old schema and new schema as follows to make the comparison:

Query series cardinality in the weather measurement:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb"

influxdb.cardinality(
    bucket: "yourBucket",
    start: -1y,
    predicate: (r) => r._measurement == "weather",
)
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/best-practices/resolve-high-cardinality/).